# xltabular pagebreak within paragraph

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs, xltabular

I use xltabular to to write my abstract in a one-column table. The actual abstract is in the third row. Since the abstract is longer than one page, a page break is necessary. Xltabular insert a pagebreak only after a newline `\\` command (in my MWE after one blindtext). Is there a way to make the text of the third row automatically pagbreak like a normal paragraph at the bottom of the page? Thanks in advance!

[image: Page break at end of paragraph]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
10pt,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\geometry{
    landscape=false,
    left=30mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
}

\spacing{1.5}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Abstract}

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{| X |}
    \hline
    First row: some information.\\
    \hline
    Second row: some more information.\\
    \hline
    Abstract begins in third row.\\
    \blindtext\\
    \blindtext\\
    \blindtext\\
    \blindtext\\
    End of abstract.\\
    \hline
    Fourth row: some information. \\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Edit:

This is how it looks in Word. I just inserted empty lines in the abstract cell.

[image: How it should look]

Edit 2:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,
10pt,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\geometry{
    landscape=false,
    left=30mm,
    right=25mm,
    top=25mm,
    bottom=25mm,
}

\spacing{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    
\chapter{Abstract}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{| X |}
    \hline
    First row: some information.\\
    \hline
    Second row: some more information.\\
    \hline
    Abstract begins in third row.\\
    \blindtext\\
    \blindtext\\
    \blindtext\\
    \blindtext\\
    End of abstract.\\
    \hline
    Fourth row: some information. \\
    \hline
\end{xltabular}

\clearpage

\begin{framed}
    First row: some information.
\end{framed}
\begin{framed}
    Second row: some more information.  
\end{framed}
\begin{oframed}
    Abstract begins in third row.\\
    \blindtext\\
    \blindtext\\
    \blindtext\\
    \blindtext\\
    End of abstract.
\end{oframed}
\begin{framed}
    Fourth row: some information.
\end{framed}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: only ny breaking the text by hand and finishing the paragraph early ending the table row and then re-starting

Comment: but really a 1-column table isn't doing anything useful (if that is your real case) I would set this with the text at the top level so it breaks easily.

Comment: So you mean writting just the text and draw frames around?

Comment: The simple `framed` package can break across pages.

Comment: Also `tcolorbox` can easily create boxes that break across pages...

Comment: @Bernard Can you do a little example? That would help I think :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some extension of interesting @Bernard answer (+1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{framed} 
\newcommand\Rule{\hspace*{-9pt}\rule[0.5ex]{\dimexpr\linewidth+18pt}{0.2pt}\par}

\title{The Seven Families of Lake Pipple-Popple}
\author{Edward Lear}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\maketitle

\textbf{ABSTRACT}
\begin{oframed}
    \lipsum[1]
\Rule
    \lipsum[1]
\Rule
    \lipsum[1]
\Rule
    \lipsum[1]
\Rule
    \lipsum[1][1]
\end{oframed}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I got some nice results with `\setlength{\FrameSep}{\tabcolsep}
\newcommand{\FramedRule}{\vspace*{-0.5\baselineskip}\newline\hspace*{-\tabcolsep}\rule[0pt]{\textwidth+2\tabcolsep}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-0.5\topsep}\newline}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with `oframed`:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \usepackage{ebgaramond} 
    \usepackage{framed} %
    %\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
    \title{The Seven Families of Lake Pipple-Popple}
    \author{Edward Lear}
     \usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{oframed}
    \begin{abstract}
        \lipsum
    \end{abstract}
    \end{oframed}

    \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is just one "row". But I need 4 rows. Further, it seems like framed insert a horizontal line befor the pagebreak.

Comment: Yes, the contents of the environment has a frame on each page. Note there also exists a `shaded` environment.

Comment: I think the oframe environment fixes this, but I couldn't figure out how to combine frame to get a the table-like layout.

Comment: I'll have a look  tomorrow (iit's getting late here) at the details of this environment, which I happened to use  long ago.

Comment: Thanks! I've added a template from Word. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: @DanielStich: I tested `oframed`, and posted the result. It wasn't so long finally. Is it more lije you want?

Comment: The pagebreak looks good but I don't get the rows like in the picture I've posted :/

Comment: I'm noy sure to fully understand. Do you want some paragraphs to be separated by a rule?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tag you. Yeah basically, but also vertical rules. I think the Word example should clearify how I want the layout to look like.

Comment: @DanielStich:  I don't use Word, so it's not installed on my system, and  I can't see what exactly you want. Could you post a link to an example, or explain what my proposition is lacking?

Comment: Ok I've added a second MWE (see edit 2). In the xltabular approach, only the pagebreak is handled not as I want it. The text in the third "row" of the table should break as normal text would do. Anything else ragarding layout is fine. On the other hand in the approach with framed and oframed the framed text sections "first row, second row, third row, fourth row"  are seperated by vertical white space. If I try to just use one oframed environment (not included in MWE) and add `\hrule` I get not the vertical spacing as in `lxtabular` and the rule does not span over width of frame.